# Is this a good Dart idiom to temporarily suspend the current computation?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I'd like to yield the CPU in a long-ish running computation from time to time, so that other activities can be performed in the same isolate.  "await null" does what I want, but I wonder if there's a different, generally accepted Dart idiom to do the same thing?

Here's a bit of code, to illustrate what I mean:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

void main(args) async {
    burnCpu(1);
    burnCpu(2);
    burnCpu(3);
    burnCpu(4);
}

int i = 0;
var r = new Random();

void burnCpu(int id) async {
  while (i < 1000000) {
    i++;
    print("$id: $i");
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
        var a = (j / r.nextDouble()).toString() + r.nextDouble().toString();
    }
    await null;
    // See Dart language spec v.2.2 section 16.34, "Await Expressions"
  }
}
```

As expected, this produces the following:

```
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
1: 5
2: 6
3: 7
4: 8
1: 9
2: 10
...
```

I'm pretty happy with just using "await null;", and if my understanding of the language spec is correct, it's guaranteed to work.  But "await null", while logical, is a little obscure-looking.  I searched around a bit to see if I could find a common idiom for this, but came up empty.  Is there one?

Comment: It is difficult to understand which question you need the answer to.

Comment: I'm asking if there's a more popular, intuitive idiom that does the same thing as "await null".